# Binding listbox with MVVM Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm, windows-phone-8

Hi i'm new using MVVM and i'm trying to binding a listbox but it doesn't work. Here's my code

**Model**

```
   public class Musicmodel : INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
    //variables privadas

      private String _artista;
      private Uri _href;
      private String _informacion;
      private Double _Dvalue;

    public String artista
    {
        get
         {
            return this._artista;  
          }
        set
        {
            this._artista= value;

            this.RaisePropertyChanged("artista");
        }
    }

    public Uri href { 
        get {

            return this._href;
         }

        set
        {
            this._href = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("href");
        }

    }
    public String informacion {
        get 
        {
            return this._informacion;
        }

        set
        {
            this._informacion = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("informacion");
        }
    }
    public Double Dvalue
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Dvalue;
        }
        set
        {
            this._Dvalue = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("Dvalue");
        }

    }



    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
   }
  }
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class DownloadFileViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private WebClient clienteDownload;


    private ObservableCollection<Model.Music>_musicSource= new ObservableCollection<Model.Music>();

    public ObservableCollection<Model.Music> musicSource
    {
        get
        {
            return this._musicSource;
        }
        set
        {
            this._musicSource = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("musicSource");
        }
    }


    private int index = 0;


    //request para descargar la canción
    public void request(Model.Musicmodel item)
    {
        this.clienteDownload = new WebClient();
        this.clienteDownload.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(clienteDownload_DownloadProgressChanged);

        //agregamos el item al music
        this.musicSource.Add(item);

        this.clienteDownload.OpenReadAsync(this.musicSource[index].href);

    }


    private void clienteDownload_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
       this.musicSource[index].Dvalue=(double)e.ProgressPercentage;

    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }


  }
  }
```

**View**

```
            <ListBox x:Name="list" ItemsSource="{Binding musicSource}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding artista}"/>
                        <ProgressBar Value="{Binding Dvalue}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

**Code Behind**

```
          protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
          {

            DownloadFileViewModel download = new DownloadFileViewModel();
            Model.Music newMusic = new Model.Music() { href = new   Uri("http://media1.li.ru/b/4/mp3/2/95366/953662_14Friday_Im_In_Love.mp3", UriKind.Absolute), artista = "the cure" };
            download.request(newMusic);
            this.DataContext = download;
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

         }
```

I've debuged this and the download works fine and my  ObservableCollection fills correctly whithout any problem but when i try to binding my listbox fails.
please what do i'm doing wrong?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is quite simple. You initialize your musicSource property at the begining in

```
private ObservableCollection<Model.Music>_musicSource= new ObservableCollection<Model.Music>();
```

And then just add stuff to it after the request completes. The `RaiseProperyChanged("Property")` will only fire when you add a new observable collection but not when you add items to it.

Add this line again to the end of the request (when you populate your musicSource)

```
RaisePropertyChanged("musicSource");
```

This will trigger another update in the view

EDIT:

Another approach is to have an additional field like

```
private ObservableCollection<Model.Music>_anotherMusicSource= new ObservableCollection<Model.Music>();
```

And do everything on it and after that just say:

```
musicSource = _anotherMusicSource;
```

This will then trigger the notification and everything should work

Comment: Ah touché! I usually leave my properties to be set after the viewmodel has loaded so I don't suffer from requiring an INPC invoke (since it's part of the property setter). Good spot!

Comment: That's what I usually do as well. Untill I have everything that needs to go into the property I keep everything in a private field and populate it at the end which then notifies the view correctly

Comment: Thanks i have changed it but when i add a item to my   ObservableCollection throws NullReferenceException becasue it doesn't initialize. what should i do?

Comment: here's the throw   
        this.musicSource.Add(item);

Comment: Just make sure you create a local scoped list and assign it to `musicSource` after you've filled it. Alternatively, instantiate your list as you have already done, but make sure you call `RaisePropertyChanged("musicSource")` after you have populated the list (in fact you need to make sure it gets called after you set the `DataContext` on the view otherwise the view won't see the property update) - on a side note, are you using an MVVM framework?

Answer (score 1):

You have an underscore in your property name

```
private ObservableCollection<Model.Musicmodel> musicSource= new ObservableCollection<Model.Musicmodel>();

public ObservableCollection<Model.Musicmodel> _musicSource
{
    get
    {
        return this.musicSource;
    }
    set
    {
        this.musicSource = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("musicSource");
    }
 }
```

You have this mixed up - the underscore should (traditionally) be on the private member, not the public - your binding is targeting `musicSource` which is private

The standard convention which is advocated for .NET is:

```
// Private member variables
private int _someInteger;

// Public ones
public int SomeInteger { get { ... } set { ... } }
```

Comment: Check your output window when running - it should show binding errors such as: `System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'IsCurrentLocation' property not found on 'object'` - check that and make sure you are binding to the object you expect

Comment: And don't forget that your RaisePropertyChanged handler needs to raise a property changed for `musicSource` - don't change that. If you can post the amended code that would be useful

Comment: Did you set the `DataContext` on your view? The `DataContext` is the target object for bindings - I'd assume you want to make the datacontext at the root of your view point to your viewmodel

Comment: Yes i my view i have this

Comment: DownloadFileViewModel download = new DownloadFileViewModel();  this.DataContext = download;

Comment: Well - it looks ok from my perspective - I'd just check the output window for binding errors. I think they don't show in Express versions of Visual Studio but you can turn them on - what version of VS are you using?

Comment: Thanks a lot of for your help. My listbox now works perfectly :D